# WatchKit Xcode 7.0 Beta 2 Build Error / Circular Segues / "exit code 255"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, watchkit

While working on a project for WatchKit 2 on XCode 7.0 beta 2, I have encountered the following build errors:
[image]

Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

error: The folder “Interface.wkstoryboardc” doesn’t exist.

I had a storyboard with segues from view 1-2-3-4, with a final segue back from view 4-1. Each views controller had one button with a segue to the next view in the list.

[image]

Removing the segue from view 4 to 1 caused this error to go away.
If this were an iPhone project, I would use an unwind segue. However, I cannot see how to do this on the watch. Has anyone else seen this behavior? Is this expected behavior, or a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hierarchical interface is intended to allow the user to "drill down" into child views. You can't push a parent view onto a child view. Unwind segues aren't available in WatchKit as far as I know.

One way to accomplish this would be to implement a button in the last interface controller that calls `popToRootController`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, replace your problematic segues with button actions like this:

```
 - (IBAction)backToStart {

  [self popToRootController];
 }

 - (IBAction)backToPrevious {

  [self popController];
 }
```